# Adding multiple nested Fragments is it a bad practice?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my requirements i need to add multiple nested fragments as am using navigation drawer as a main navigation so am using nested fragments like lets say Fragment a->b->c->d-> like that i have created is that a right way to do with using multiple fragments like would cost anything for application ? As beginner am very confused what to do with is it a bad practice i may be dumb question ! any solution you people are here to help beginner like us thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bad practice, but mostly we should keep fragments in Activity, instead nesting them which is complex but sometimes, it also depends on design of apps, which we must have to follow either by nested fragments or whatever.

In case of Navigation Drawer, you can be enough by adding fragment to navigation list items click and then start activity on fragment click.

Fragments are very useful. 
An Activty can have multiple fragments ,and fragments cannot have fragments inside them.

In Android 4.2  there was support for Nested Fragments Where you can use fragment inside other fragment. But your fragment must be dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: i have added dynamic fragments inside a fragment